# How to create a "terminal server server" in xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal-server, nx, xubuntu

I am pretty new to system administration, and I am definitively new to serverfault, so apologies should my question not be following SF standards to the 100%.

This is my problem: I have a xubuntu machine with a number of accounts on it that I need to access remotely (in the same LAN but not in the same room). I would like my users to be able to use the GUI. More specifically I want to emulate the behaviour you experience when connecting via "terminal server client" to a windows machine.

If I got the documentation right, I **can't use VNC** as I do not need to "spec" an *existing* GUI session running on the remote machine: I want to open a *new* GUI session from the remote machine.

I considered a number of possibilities (XDMCP, FreeNX, the not-so-free NX from NoMachine...) but from ubuntu's documentation it looks like the best supported way of doing this is **by using LSPT**, as this is the architecture they already use in their thin client configuration (edubuntu).

Now, this is the question: although I could find in various places references to the fact you can use LSPT to do set up thick clients, **I could not find any documentation on how to do this**. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for you time! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After various tries, I finally managed to find a solution to my problems. Here's the how-to, it has been tested with:

- Xubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala
- Freenx server  v. 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.3.0)
- NX client from nomachine.com v. 3.4.0-5

**SERVER SIDE:**

Basically follow the instructions from the [ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX). You will need to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freenx
sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
```

I used the default configuration parameters for the install procedure (**update:** apparently launching the configuration procedure is superfluous if you are fine with the default parameters and encryption keys). Once installed, make sure your server is running by issuing

```
sudo /etc/init.d/freenx-server start
```

**CLIENT SIDE:**

1. I chose to use the the free-as-in-beer client from [nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/). If you are following this how-to, you will need to download the client from their website.
2. Once installed you will need to configure your session to work with XFCE.
3. In General->Desktop select Unix/Custom and press the button "Settings"
4. In the "Application" fieldset, select *Run the following command* and enter the command: `startxfce4`
5. In the "Option" fieldset, select *New virtual desktop*

Now you will only have to enter your hostname, user and password and... *voilà!* you should be able to log in to your server!

Thanks to those who took the time to try to answer my question, anyhow! :)

Comment: As ubuntu is more and more deprecating call to upstart job, I would recommand to use `service freenx-server start` instead of `/etc/init.d` though it will also work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest XDMCP, it's the longstanding supported way of doing this with X.

Comment: Thanks PJC for you answer, but correct if I am wrong: XDMCP sends usr/pwd unencripted, so - unless there's a way to tunnel that through SSH - I would rather pick some kind of more secure protocol.

Comment: there is a Secure Display Manager (SDM) in the debian repos; i believe it's main focus was using ssh for logins.  i can't tell how well-supported it is at present though; it doesn't seem to be in active development.  http://packages.debian.org/sid/sdm